# C# detect if calls were in the same UI action

Tags: c#, winforms, undo

I have some nice, working edit-undo functionality in my winforms application. It works using a `CommandStack` class, which is two `Stack<IStateCommand>`s (one for undo, one for redo). Each command has an `Execute` and an `Undo` method, and the `CommandStack` object itself has an event that is fired when the stacks are changed.

The `CommandStack` also works out if the LogCommand method is called from its own Undo function, and therefore adding it to the redo stack, rather than the undo stack. This is done by simply adding the current `ManagingThreadId` to a `List<int>` object, then removing it after the Undo command is completed (as opposed to using the stack trace, which I believe would be much slower and a bit dirty).

There is a lot of different commands within my application so this formula is sort of set in stone as it'll take me a few days to redo all those `IStateCommand`s implementations.

The only problem with this, currently, some UI events within also call other UI events, both of which log an `IStateCommand` to the undo history. Is there any way in C# that I can detect if the LogCommand function has already been called from the same UI event (Click, DragDrop, SelectedIndexChanged, TextChanged, etc), then I can combine the commands into one command (using my `CommandList` class, which also inherits `IStateCommand`)?

I've thought of saving the current time when the undo event was called, then if the next command is logged less than x milliseconds later, combine them in the history, but this seems a bit sloppy. I've also considered searching the stack trace, but I don't really know what to look for to find the root UI event, nor do I know whether I would tell the different between one button click, then a different click on the same button.

It may also be helpful to know that all of these commands are being called from the UI thread from event handlers (mostly from events from custom user controls). The only part of my application that uses another thread runs after most UI events, after the undo history is logged.

Thanks!

**Sort Version**

The same method is being called twice from the same UI event (eg, MouseUp, DragDrop). The second time this method is called, how do I check that it has already been called once by the same UI event?

**Edit: The solution (sort of)**

It's a bit of a dirty one as I don't have the time to completely re-write this system. However I've implemented it in such a way that gives the option not to be so dirty in the future.

The solution is based on one of Erno's comments on his answer (so I will mark his answer as accepted), where he suggests added a parameter. I added another overload to my `LogCommand(IStackCommand)` method in the `CommandStack` class, `LogCommand(IStackCommand, string)`. The string is the actionId, which is stored for each command, and if this string is the same as the last, the commands are combined. This gives the option to go through each event and give a unique ID.

However, *the dirty part* - to get it working before we have to show the client, the `actionId` defaults to `System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.ToString()`, ouch!! Since the cursor position is not changed while the UI thread is executing, this combines each command. It actually even combines TextChanged commands (as long as they don't move their mouse!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be an option to add a local stack of called-commands to a command.

When a command executes other commands add the command to the local stack so you can undo the commands on this local stack when the command must be undone or redone.

**EDIT**

I am not quite sure what you don't understand.

I would simply add a CommandList property to the StateCommand. Everytime the StateCommand invokes/triggers another StateCommand it should add the new StateCommand to the CommandList. So the global CommandList keeps track of the Commands that can be undone from the UI and each StateCommand keeps track of the StateCommands it invoked (so these are not added to the global undo CommandList)

**EDIT 2**

If you can't or do not want to change to that setup you would have to pass a parameter to the execution of the commands that links them together.

Comment: Seems the best solution, create a stack for each base method call, and have any resulting method calls write to that. Then you can add these stacks to the master undo/redo stacks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, or my question wasn't clear enough :/ The IStateCommand isn't calling the other IStateCommand if that's what you mean. A UI Event is a) logging an IStateCommand, and b) calling another action, which happens to eventually log another IStateCommand.

Comment: I already have a CommandList, which also inherits IStateCommand and can execute/undo multiple commands at the same time. How would you suggest I find the base method call?

Comment: @Erno, can you rephrase the answer a bit please? Either I don't understand, or you're telling me how to write a CommandList class, which I already have, my question is more 'how do I create one for each base method call'.

Comment: @ConnellWatkins - I added to my answer

Comment: Okay, thank you. The StateCommand doesn't invoke/trigger the other StateCommands. This is my problem. In this case, two StateCommands are being created from the same MouseUp event. Both of these StateCommands are seperate instances, how do I tell that they have been created from the same MouseUp event?

Comment: @ConnellWatkins - Just don't ;-) Trigger a single command and let the command trigger/invoke other commands. The single command will be the identification of the MouseUp event. In other words: will show you what command have been trigger by the same action. If you can't or do not want to change to that setup you would have to pass a parameter to the execution of the commands that links them together.

Comment: Ah I see.. it's quite a big system and I'm already over my deadline, so a complete redesign of the way every event works isn't the best option. Passing a parameter is a good option, but this is happening in a few different places and this could be a pain to maintain. I may have to resort to programatically accessing the stack trace or something :/ Thanks for your help though

Comment: @ConnellWatkins - Shortcuts make long delays... I you do not clean up now and inject this quick and dirty solution you not only continue a flaw you also add a hack. I know time pressure can be tough but this might backfire real soon.

Comment: @Erno, I know, I've experienced this plenty of times before. I take big pride in my code and more often than not would go for a re-design when something like this happens (I hate dirty code, when I'm forced to write some, I feel forced to add a comment explaining why I did it this way xD) As it happens I found a not-so-dirty workaround using your parameter idea, which I will put in the question if you'd like to read :)

Comment: @ConnellWatkins - No problem. I added the parameter suggestion to my answer so others may benefit without digging in the comments. Good luck!

Comment: Brilliant, I've accepted your answer and put my solution in the question. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. You can see what I mean by 'not-so-dirty', as it does give me the option to later on, spend a few days doing it properly ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to inspect the method stack and analyze it method-by-method:

```
    StackTrace st = new StackTrace();

    for ( int i=0; i<st.FrameCount; i++ )
{
    StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(i);
    MethodBase mb = sf.GetMethod();

    // do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: StackTrace is only working with pdb files which are usually not deployed with release version.

Comment: Yes, but say I click a button which logs two commands. I then undo, that'll undo both commands that the button has logged. If there is a seperate button, that only logs one command, and I hit it twice in a row, I only want to undo one click.

Comment: @baalazamon, I didn't realise this either, I thought the advantage of the PDB file is that each method in the stack trace can contain the code file and line number too.

Comment: @baalazamon: Are you sure? Have you checked it out? I have it running in front of my eyes, Release build, no *.pdbs at hand.

Comment: Checked it again and it seems that this is in fact the Debug build with no *.pdbs. In a Release build the stack trace is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you need exactly to achieve, but I implemented something similar, maybe you can get some ideas...

In summary, you can store some information in a ***ThreadStatic*** variable. Then, any time you want to log a command, inspect the thread static variable to find out the context in which you are logging the command. If it's empty, you are starting a new command logging sequence. If not, you are inside a sequence.

Maybe you can store the entry event (e.g. Click, DragDrop,...), or the command itself... It depends on your needs.
When the initial event callback is completed, clean the static variable to signal that the sequence has been completed.

I successfully implemented a similar strategy to **track commands** executed upon an object model. I encapsulated the logic within an IDisposable class that also implemented the **reference counting** to handle the **nested usings**. The first *using* started the sequence, subsequents *using* statements increased and decreased the reference counting to know when the sequence was completed. The outermost context disposing fired an event containing all the nested commands. In my specific case it has worked perfectly, I don't know if it may fulfill your needs...

Comment: How do I "store the entry event", if I knew how to do this, I could store a static variable of the lastEntryEvent, then when a command is logged, check if the entry event is the same as this variable, and if so, combine these `IStateCommand`s in the undo history stack.

Comment: Maybe you could do it with an aspect. Then you could decorate the event handler method with an attribute, and perform the store and reference counter within the aspect. This would keep the code clean. I use PostSharp to do some things like this.